# BoomMenu not showing

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a boom Menu.my device is an android 10.Am using BoomMenu 2.1.1
this is my xml code .Problem is that my activity crushes when opened with the below error

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at com.nightonke.boommenu.BoomMenuButton.createPieces(BoomMenuButton.java:408)
    at com.nightonke.boommenu.BoomMenuButton.doLayoutJobs(BoomMenuButton.java:390)
    at com.nightonke.boommenu.BoomMenuButton.onLayout(BoomMenuButton.java:376)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22090)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6358)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22090)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6358)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1775)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22090)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6358)
    at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:142)
    at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:41)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:888)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22090)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6358)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22090)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6358)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22090)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6358)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22090)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6358)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22090)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6358)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:783)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22090)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6358)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3239)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2735)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1821)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7916)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:980)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:804)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:739)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:965)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
```

Below is my current xml and java code.I set `bmb_buttonEnum`  and `bmb_piecePlaceEnum` and `bmb_buttonPlaceEnum` from my activity(Even without setting or instantiating the BoomMenuButton,still crushes on openint the activity)

```
 <com.nightonke.boommenu.BoomMenuButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
     android:id="@+id/bmb"

   />

developer_options = (BoomMenuButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bmb);
                developer_options.setButtonEnum(ButtonEnum.Ham);
                developer_options.setPiecePlaceEnum(PiecePlaceEnum.HAM_3);
                developer_options.setButtonPlaceEnum(ButtonPlaceEnum.HAM_3);
```

i had tried to use the below with nothing on the activity side but stil crushes

```
    <com.nightonke.boommenu.BoomMenuButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:bmb_buttonEnum="ham"
    app:bmb_piecePlaceEnum="piecePlace_ham_4"
    app:bmb_buttonPlaceEnum="buttonPlace_ham_4"
    android:id="@+id/bmb"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set `button-enum, piece-place-enum, and button-place-enum` in .xml or .java, you  have to initialize the builder for each button in your activity.

Create an array of images to show on each boomButton (unless you want them to be the same)

`Integer[] bmbImages = {R.drawable.ic_image, R.drawable.ic_image2, R.drawable.ic_image3}`

Create an array for the text inside

`String[] bmbText = {getString(R.string.your_string), getString(R.string.text2), getString(R.string.text3)};`

Loop through each boomButton to customize

```
for (int i = 0; i < developer_options.getPiecePlaceEnum().pieceNumber(); i++) {
     HamButton.Builder builder = new HamButton.Builder()
        .normalImageRes(bmbImages[i])
        .normalTextRes(bmbText[i])
        .subNormalTextRes("array of subtext here");

     developer_options.addBuilder(builder);}
```

Here is the link where I got this information from:
[BoomMenu on GitHub](https://github.com/Nightonke/BoomMenu/wiki/Ham-Button)